# Displaying an indeterminate checkbox with GWT Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gwt, checkbox

I want to be able to set a Bootstrap checkbox to "indeterminate" status in GWT.  I wrote the following code:

```
/**
 * JavaScript to give an ID'd element in a form the focus
 * 
 * @param checkbox      Element to manipulate
 * @param indeterminate True if indeterminate, false if not
 */
public static native void setIndeterminate (Element checkbox, boolean indeterminate) /*-{
    checkbox.indeterminate = indeterminate;
}-*/;
```

Running this in Chrome the debugger tells me that the checkbox is set to indeterminate = true, but it still displays as unselected.  When I display [this page](https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/) I see the indeterminate checkbox correctly, so it's not a browser problem.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both GWT and GWT Bootstrap, a Checkbox is a span, whose first element is the input checkbox.  So the problem is fixed with this:

```
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;

Element    element = checkbox.getElement ();
Element    child = element.getFirstChildElement ();
if (child != null)
    element = child;

setIndeterminate (element, indeterminate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want JSNI code for that?

You can use the following

```
Checkbox checkbox = new Checkbox("Some-Label");
checkbox.getElement().setAttribute("indeterminate", true /*Or false*/);
```

**EDIT**

Just checked some docs and blog posts. Apparently, GWT doesn't support indeterminate in checkboxes. Apparently there is a work around.

Whenever you want the indeterminate value, set the checkbox to null. Then use CSS tricks to style the checkbox.

Comment: 1: Does not do the same thing as the JSNI code. 2: Unfortunately, doesn't fix the problem, still not displaying as an indeterminate checkbox

Comment: Could you point me to one of those posts? In my searching I haven't found any of the posts you mention.  Thank you!